# Play framework - classnotfoundexception when calling method from controller. Works fine when testing with junit

Tags: java, junit, playframework, playframework-2.1

I am using Play 2.1.1. I have a CSV parser class that looks like this:

```
    public List<Bean> readCsv() throws Exception {  
    List<Bean> beans= new ArrayList<Bean>();
    ICsvDozerBeanReader beanReader = null;
    try{
        //String csvName = 
        String csvName = "file.csv";

            beanReader = new CsvDozerBeanReader(new FileReader(csvName), CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE);

            beanReader.getHeader(true); //to ignore header
            beanReader.configureBeanMapping(Bean.class, FIELD_MAPPING);

            Bean bean = null;
             while( (bean= beanReader.read(Bean.class, processors)) != null ) {
                 beans.add(bean);
             } 
    }finally{
        if( beanReader != null ) {
            beanReader.close();
    }
    }
```

This method works with junit:

```
@Test
public void testCsvParser() {
    CSVLoaderServiceImpl service = new CSVLoaderServiceImpl();
    List<Bean> beans = null;
    try {
        beans = service.readCsv();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    assertEquals(236, beans.size());
}
```

If I copy this exact code into one of the controller methods in Application.java. The application falls over with a class not found exception.

```
public static Result jsonMap(){


    CSVLoaderServiceImpl service = new CSVLoaderServiceImpl();
    List<Bean> beans = null;
    try {
        beans = service.readCsv();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ok(beans.toString());

}
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: packageName.Bean
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at sbt.PlayCommands$$anonfun$53$$anonfun$55$$anon$2.loadClass(PlayCommands.scala:535)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:266)
    at org.apache.commons.lang.ClassUtils.getClass(ClassUtils.java:754)
    at org.apache.commons.lang.ClassUtils.getClass(ClassUtils.java:802)
    at org.apache.commons.lang.ClassUtils.getClass(ClassUtils.java:785)
    at org.dozer.util.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:3
```

I think the class loader is different when Play handles kicking off the method to junit. Really not sure how to fix it.

UPDATE: This is the line where the classnotfoundexception occurs:

```
beanReader.configureBeanMapping(Bean.class, FIELD_MAPPING);
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated

Many thanks

Comment: Are you sure you have the right import locations? The controller package may be in a different path than the other classes calling the import.